# Adding to heap and printing

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap

we have been learning heaps in class and my teacher has hardly taught us a thing.  According to the notes (which is all that was given to complete this task) this should create a heap.  My issue however is I do not see any way to add data to the heap or what would go in main.  I have never used heaps before so I am very new to the subject.  Any advice at all would be appreciated thanks!

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class Heap{
   public:
    void ReheapDown(int root,int bottom);
    void ReheapUp(int root, int bottom);
    void swap(ItemType * a, ItemType * b);

    ItemType * elements;
    int numEle;

};
template<class ItemType>
void Heap<ItemType>::swap(ItemType *a, ItemType *b)
{
    ItemType x;
    x = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = x;
}

template<class ItemType>
void Heap<ItemType>::ReheapDown(int root, int bottom)
{
    int maxChild;
    int rightChild;
    int leftChild;

    leftChild = root*2 + 1;
    rightChild = root*2 +2;

    if(leftChild <= bottom)
    {
        if(leftChild == bottom)
            maxChild = leftChild;
        else
        {
            if(elements[leftChild] <= elements[rightChild])
                maxChild = rightChild;
            else
                maxChild = leftChild;
        }
        if(elements[root] < elements[maxChild])
        {
            swap(elements[root],elements[maxChild]);
            ReheapDown(maxChild,bottom);
        }
    }
}


template<class ItemType>
void Heap<ItemType>::ReheapUp(int root, int bottom)
{
    int parent;
    if(bottom > root)
    {
        parent = (bottom -1) / 2;
        if(elements[parent] < elements[bottom])
        {
            swap(elements[parent],elements[bottom]);
            ReheapUp(root,parent);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `main()`, you need create an instance of class `Heap`, then set the value of its data members, and build the heap by calling its member function:
BTW, there's a problem in your code when calling `swap`, you should add an address-of operator (&) before your actual parameters.

```
int main()
{
    Heap<int> heap;
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    heap.elements = array;
    heap.numEle = sizeof array / sizeof(int);

    int start;
    for (start = (heap.numEle-2)/2; start >=0; start--) {
        heap.ReheapDown(start, heap.numEle - 1); // this is the Button-Up version of heapify
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < heap.numEle; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", heap.elements[i]);
    }

    // test the Top-down version of heapify.
    heap.elements = array;

    int end;
    for(end = 1; end < heap.numEle; ++end)
        heap.ReheapUp(0, end); // this is the Top-down version of heapify

    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < heap.numEle; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", heap.elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this print out the elements in the proper order? When I ran it it just printed out 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 which is not in heap form

Comment: After adding an address-of operator (&) before your actual parameters when caling `swap`, it works for me, the program print: 7 5 6 4 2 1 3 which is a max-heap.